# Kotlin: function setSelection() doesn't work outside onItemSelected() function

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner and when I select something from the list some action happens:

```
val arrayAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, carBrandList)
        binding.spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        binding.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long,
            ) {
                refuelList.clear()
                realTimeUpdates(carIdList[position])
                saveData(requireContext(), carIdList[position])
                saveSpinnerPosition(requireContext(), position)
            }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }
    }
```

I want to store spinner position in Shared Preferences and it works.
I want to retrieve spinner position if an user opens particular fragment.
How can I use function `setSelection()` outside this code? `setSelection()` only works for me if it is in `onItemSelected()` function

Answer (score 0):

It should work outside the `onItemSelected()`, just be sure that you saved the correct spinner position in Shared Preferences.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't. Event when I try to test and type for example binding.spinner.setSelection(2) outside onItemSelected() nothing happens. It works only if I type adapterView.setSelection(2) inside onItemSelected(). When testing im passing correct spinner position values but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I see, please share your `saveSpinnerPosition(requireContext(), position)` implementation and the whole code that you use the `setSelection()` outside the `onItemSelected()`.